# Matplotlib - How to set the distance (in mm/cm/points...) between the xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been looking on the internet for a long time but couldn't figure out how to make it. I need to draw several figures whose xticks are defined as numpy.arange(1,N), N being different for each figure. I want the spacing between the xticks to be identical on all figures (e.g. 1 cm), that is, the width of each figure must depend on the size of numpy.arange(1,N). Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with a combination of careful control of your axes size (as a fraction of the figure), `ax.set_xlim` and `fig.set_size_inches` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches) to set the real size of the figure.

ex

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
 ax.set_xlim([0,N])
 fig.set_size_inches([N/2.54,h])
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon @tcaswell's answer, here is how I do it when I want to micro-manage the real dimension of my axis and of the ticks inter-distance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

#------------------------------------------------------ define xticks setup ----

xticks_pos = np.arange(11) # xticks  relative position in xaxis
N = np.max(xticks_pos) - np.min(xticks_pos) # numbers of space between ticks
dx = 1 / 2.54 # fixed space between xticks in inches
xaxis_length = N * dx

#------------------------------------------------------------ create figure ----

#---- define margins size in inches ----

left_margin  = 0.5
right_margin = 0.2
bottom_margin = 0.5
top_margin = 0.25

#--- calculate total figure size in inches ----

fwidth = left_margin + right_margin + xaxis_length
fheight = 3

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fwidth, fheight))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

#---------------------------------------------------------------- create axe----

#---- axes relative size ----

axw = 1 - (left_margin + right_margin) / fwidth
axh = 1 - (bottom_margin + top_margin) / fheight

x0 = left_margin / fwidth
y0 = bottom_margin / fheight

ax0 = fig.add_axes([x0, y0, axw, axh], frameon=True)

#---------------------------------------------------------------- set xticks----

ax0.set_xticks(xticks_pos)

plt.show(block=False)
fig.savefig('axis_ticks_cm.png')
```

This results in a figure of 11.8 cm with a xaxis of 10 cm with 1cm space between each ticks:

[image]